# Flooring a concrete deck, without raising the floor (much)

Tags: flooring, deck

I bought a house with a concrete deck 14x14' in size. I'd like to install some sort of flooring on the deck, however, I am worried about two things:

1. The weather conditions, especially snow and rain, are likely to cause damage to the floor, so I need something that lasts, and the less maintenance the better
2. The floor of the deck is only 6" below the living room entrance, so I can't raise the floor much without risking flooding the house.

I've been looking at a standard wood deck, but as I understand, it requires some metal posts, then a wooden frame, and then the floorboards, amounting to at least 6" of height. Composite seems to be better, but the price bites, and it also requires a wooden frame underneath, I can't just lay the composite boards on the concrete directly. I can't go with ceramics, because the wife is totally against that, she wants something nicer and warmer. Are there any other options, materials, or maybe a way to install a regular treated wood floor without raising it too much?

Comment: Is the current concrete deck flat (as opposed to cracked and irregular)? Does it properly drain away from the house?

Comment: Yes to both questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rubber tile or mat would be one simple approach - see duckboards for another method/approach in polymers or sometimes treated wood.

Given a solid, correctly sloped concrete substrate, pressure-treated 2x4 sleepers and a deck with no posts, etc. should work just fine - the 2x4's can even be laid flat, since the concrete deck is taking the load directly.

Paint on or pour on rubber (acrylic/polyurethane, possibly with rubber granules) coatings as for pool decks or perhaps tennis courts might also work, and might cost less.

Comment: Thanks. The deck is a square slab of concrete, if it is sloped (and I suppose it is, since water runs off) it is only slightly. I'll look up duckboards and rubber tile. So you're saying I should be able to make do with a grid of flat laid 2x4s, covered with whatever I basically prefer. What about water damage to the 2x4s? If I lay them in a grid, will they not be holding rainwater inside the grid, and rotting? Also, what kind of wood is recommended for the grid?

Comment: Sleepers are not a "grid" - they are parallel, like joists, laid in the same direction as the drainage slope, so that drainage is not impeded. I already said pressure-treated (ie, as close to rot-proof-wood as you can buy, though I would only call it rot-resistant, not "proof.") You'll typically get a couple decades of service in practice.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Thanks, I'm off to fill a bucket and figure out the slope direction :)

Comment: I would rip down PVC "lumber" for the sleepers, and paint them in anti-UV paint.  Any wood, even Trex, in direct contact with often-wet concrete is going to have a short service life.

Answer (score 0):

EKKI wood is almost indestructible .Its a African hardwood used by marine and harbor works and will last over 20 years submerged in water without rotting. If you can find a supplier it will definitely  do the trick. Get your joists and decking in EKKI and it will outlast you.

Comment: Submerged in water is trivial. Wet and dry or damp will rot wood. Submerged wood of most wood lasts and lasts, hundreds of years, many/most species.

Comment: Also, Ekki is probably eye-wateringly expensive, especially in the quantity the OP asked about.